# How to configure authentication in MongoDB Java REST server?

Tags: java, mongodb, rest

Just don't get where and how to put credentials in this framework

https://sites.google.com/site/mongodbjavarestserver/con

I've set auth=true in mongoser.proeperties

this is how auth.properties looks like:

```
# use mongoreadonly realm for read only queries
# use mongoreadwrite realm for read and write
# use admin realm for read, write, delete, create

reader: aaabbbccc, mongoreadonly
writer: zzzxxxccc, mongoreadwrite
admin: abcabcabc, admin
```

For now my MongoDB has Admin user "admin1" with password "pwd1" (which works with other clients fine).

I've tried:

```
admin1: pwd1, admin
```

and

```
admin: pwd1, admin1
```

No success:

```
curl -i "http://myhosting.de:8081/query/test/abc"
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: basic realm="Mongodb Realm"
Content-Length: 0
```

Any idea?

**Update.** I looks like auth=true secures REST API, but that is not what I am looking for. I was looking for how to connect to already secured Mongo DB.

The new output message is:

```
{"status":"Mongodb: command failed [command failed [count] { \"serverUsed\" : \"127.0.0.1:27017\" , \"ok\" : 0.0 , \"errmsg\" : \"not authorized on test to execute command { count: \\\"abc\\\", query: {} }\" , \"code\" : 13}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this framework follows the conventions in Java it should be:

```
user=password[,role][,role]...
```

So to configure a user `test1` with password `pwd1` and group `admin`:

```
test1=pwd1,admin
```

Furthermore you need to pass the credentials to `curl` using the `-u` flag:

```
curl -u test1:pwd1 -i "http://myhosting.de:8081/query/test/abc"
```

Comment: I see. You were right, perhaps I defined the problem not precise enough.

My problem is, I don't want to secure REST API, but my MongoDB **is** secured (with admin1/pwd1 as credentials). I don't quite see how to configure, so that Java REST Framework can read my MongoDB.

Comment: I had a brief look and it seems this framework is not capable of perform MongoDB authentication. If you install the REST app on your MongoDB server you could restrict MongoDB to local access and switch off auth in Mongo.